# linq - get most recent associated record

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Assuming I have `Customer` and `Order` objects, where one `Customer` can have many `Orders` (so the `Order` class has a `CustomerId` property), and I want to return a collection of all `CustomerAndMostRecentOrder` objects which are defined as follows:

```
public class CustomerAndMostRecentOrder
{
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
  public Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
}
```

How would I write a Linq query which does this (I'm using Linq to SQL)?

Comment: How would you define how recent is *Most Recent* ?

Comment: It's a very good question - I'm sorry I omitted this. The people who have answered have simply defined an `OrderDate` or `PurchaseDate` property to order on, and that's fine - that's basically what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have an `CreatedDate` date in your `Order` table to get the most recent order. Then to get your `CustomerAndMostRecentOrder` object, do the following query:

```
from c in customers
join o in orders on c.ID equals o.CustomerID into co
select new CustomerAndMostRecentOrder
{
    Customer = c,
    MostRecentOrder = co.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Comment: This is great - thanks. How would I apply a where clause on the co collection?

Comment: You could use the extension methods with lamba, or use a nested query. Where do you want to filter? For example: Get all customers and the most recent order that is over £100, or get all customers and the most recent order where it's over £100?

Comment: I'm really sorry - I can't work out the difference between the two choices. If the `Customer` has no orders over £100, then I wouldn't want the `Customer` returned at all. Inner join logic. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Well that's neither of my examples actually, they'll be 3 different queries. You need to put `where co.Count(o => o.Amount > 100) > 0` after the `join` but before the `select` statement

Comment: David, I just thought. It'd be better to use the `Any` method, rather than saying `Count() > 0`. They do exactly the same thing, except the `Any` method looks neater. `where co.Any(o => o.Amount > 100)` in this example.

Comment: As I understand it .Any() is also substantially more efficient on very large datasets as the compiler stops and returns true on hitting the first object rather than counting the collection and then comparing that with zero.

Comment: @pwdst you are correct for an enumerable object. For queryables, I believe there isn't much of a performance difference though. Even still, it's good practice to use `.Any()`. You'll thank yourself when you need to replace your queryable object with an array in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
from c in customers
select new CustomerAndMostRecentOrder
    {
        Customer = c,
        MostRecentOrder = c.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.PurchaseDate).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

This will use a navigation property from customer to order. The MostRecentOrder is taken by ordering the Orders on some DateTime property and then loading the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomerAndMostRecentOrder
{
    public CustomerAndMostRecentOrder(Customer customer, Order mostRecentOrder)
    {
        Customer = customer;
        MostRecentOrder = mostRecentOrder;
    }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Order MostRecentOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
}


public class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
    {

    }
}


public static class UsageClass
{

    public static void Sample(IEnumerable<Customer> allCustomers)
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomerAndMostRecentOrder> customerAndMostRecentOrders =
            allCustomers.Select(customer => new CustomerAndMostRecentOrder(customer, customer.GetOrders().Last()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, you may want to take a look into the DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith discussed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx. Simply set your requirements on the context and you don't need to worry about filtering the children at the query level.